# Dynamic scrolling in a WPF application with ItemsControl object

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, user-interface, scroll

In my xaml, I have some object made by me. I put them in row and, if the window is too little for all, I go in a new line.

The problem is when the window is so little that, also in a new line, the elements can't be all shown. The solution is simple: scroll bar!! But, if I set the Vertical/HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to auto, it doesn't go to a newline anymore.

This is my xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
     <ItemsControl Name="ItemGroups" ItemsSource="{Binding NotifyItemUI}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

and this is a screenshot what I need as my goal:

[image]

**For example, if I resize my area vertically, and I have 3 rows of objects, in this way I can't see the third row if the window becames too little. In this case, I'd like to see a vertical scrollbar to scroll it.**

**Same thing horizontally: if I have too many elements for one single row, I have to scroll it horizontally.**

Comment: You can either set a `MaxHeight` or `MaxWidth` property on the container control to restrict the maximum number of elements to display on each row, or you can remove one of the `Scrollbar`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe looks like a `WrapPanel`, but the way you write about it suggests it is a custom control, so we cannot see what your `ItemsControl` is doing for layout.

However, `ScrollViewer` can have tricky interaction with a `Panel`. If the `Panel` measures to infinity, it will always consider itself big enough, and never tell the `ScrollViewer` it is out of room. The result is that the `ScrollViewer`does no know the scrollbar is needed. If this is your problem, then setting the `Width` and `Height` properties, or maxima as @Sheridan said, ought to fix it.